# View clipping by script

Tags: scripting

I have a scene with very large objects. I can change the view clipping manually:
3D Viewport => View properties panel on the left => Clip Start // End

By doing this, the script console shows the following line (for example with End = 1e+06):

```
bpy.context.space_data.clip_end = 1e+06
```

But if I use this line in a script, or directly in the console, an error is raised:

```
'Space_console' object has no attribute 'clip_end'.
```

Where am I wrong? Any idea to work around the problem?
Thank you!

My Blender:
version: 2.80 (sub 75), branch: master, commit date: 2019-07-29 14:47, hash: f6cb5f54494e, type: 
build date: 2019-07-29, 09:44 AM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current screen you are in has context.  A screen is made up of a number of areas.  Each has a "space".

The property panel displaying the clipping is in the 3d view space its context area type is `VIEW_3D`

The console has its own area and space types, pertinent to (... in the context of ...) running script in the console. There is no clipping or view angle etc needed for the console, it displays text and runs code.

Hence the error, the python console space has no clipping distance.

As an example,  I have a screen with 4 areas open, the 3d view, the python console, properties and the outliner.  as Illustrated below with python console code

I am interested in the view 3d area, and see that it is index 3 of all my screen areas.

Once I have the area of the right type the space is `area.spaces.active` .. (often seen as `area.spaces[0]` I prefer the former) to which I can set the clipping distance.

See docs.  https://docs.blender.org/api/master/bpy.types.SpaceView3D.html#bpy.types.SpaceView3D.clip_end

Notice how the space of a 3d view is type `SpaceView3D`

```
>>> for i, a in enumerate(C.screen.areas):
...     i, a.type
...     
(0, 'PROPERTIES')
(1, 'CONSOLE')
(2, 'OUTLINER')
(3, 'VIEW_3D')

>>> v3d_area = C.screen.areas[3]
>>> space_data = v3d_area.spaces.active
>>> space_data.clip_
                    end
                    start
>>> space_data.clip_end = 1
>>>
```

If I write an operator or panel to be displayed in the 3d view, then the space would be in context and I could simply use

```
space_data = context.space_data
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer has been really useful and clear!